# Evitar registros duplicados en C# y SQL Server

Tags: c#

Tengo este código para guardar registros,

- cuando es nuevo ingresa el registro,
- cuando se repite el registro entra en el `foreach` y muestra el mensaje (ya existe el registro) pero **de todas formas ingresa el registro**.

¿Existe alguna forma de que, cuando envíe el mensaje de que ya existe el registro, salga del ciclo y no me guarde el registro en base de datos y pueda nuevamente ingresar?

```
private void btnGuardar_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                string rpta = "";
                if (this.txtPais.Text == string.Empty)
                {
                    MensajeError("Falta ingresar algunos datos, serán remarcados");
                    errorIcono.SetError(txtPais, "Ingrese una País");
                    this.txtPais.Focus();
                }
                else
                {
                    if (this.IsNuevo)

                    // Evitar que se registren registros duplicados

                    {                        
                        DataTable tabla = NPais.Mostrar();
                        if (tabla.Rows.Count >= 0)
                        {
                            foreach (DataRow fila in tabla.Rows)
                            {
                                if (fila["nombre"].ToString() == txtPais.Text.Trim().ToUpper())
                                {
                                    MessageBox.Show("El Registro ya Existe!!","Sistema de Ventas", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                                    break;
                                }
                            }                            
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("No ha ingresado valores!!");
                        }

                        rpta = NPais.Insertar(this.txtPais.Text.Trim().ToUpper());
                    }


                    else
                    {
                        rpta = NPais.Editar(Convert.ToInt32(this.txtIdpais.Text), this.txtPais.Text.Trim().ToUpper());
                    }

                    if (rpta.Equals("OK"))
                    {
                        if (this.IsNuevo)
                        {
                            this.MensajeOk("Se Insertó de forma correcta el registro");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            this.MensajeOk("Se Actualizó de forma correcta el registro");
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        this.MensajeError(rpta);
                    }

                    this.IsNuevo = false;
                    this.IsEditar = false;
                    this.Botones();
                    this.Limpiar();
                    this.Close();

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + ex.StackTrace);
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

El problema no lo tienes tanto en el final del `foreach`, como en la situación de tu `INSERT`. Al estar fuera de cualquier condicional, siempre se te va a ejecutar.

Una posible forma de solucionarlo sería

```
if (this.IsNuevo)

    // Evitar que se registren registros duplicados
    {                        
        DataTable tabla = NPais.Mostrar();
        if (tabla.Rows.Count >= 0)
        {
            repetido = false;
            foreach (DataRow fila in tabla.Rows)
            {
                if (fila["nombre"].ToString() == txtPais.Text.Trim().ToUpper())
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("El Registro ya Existe!!","Sistema de Ventas", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    repetido = true;                                        
                    break;
                }
            }                            
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No ha ingresado valores!!");
        }
        if(!repetido)
        {
            rpta = NPais.Insertar(this.txtPais.Text.Trim().ToUpper());
        }
    }
}
```

Lo único que he modificado, es añadir una variable, que he llamado `repetido`, y que en caso de estar duplicado la pondré a `TRUE`. Una vez acabadas todas las comprobaciones, si esta variable es `TRUE`, no te hará el `INSERT`, en caso de ser `FALSE` si que te lo hace